# Canvas are not working properly in Google Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, mobile, canvas

I have made my first game in HTML5 + CSS3 + JS and I have some problems with it. It's a simple Snake game (http://5nake.ugu.pl/).
Let's get down to the problem. When you go into the game ("Gra jednoosobowa") with animations switched on (you can switch them on/off in settings ("Ustawienia")) everything is being drawn correctly, but it isn't getting cleared, so everything ends up having parts of snake like everywhere. Of course it's impossible to play a game like that. However in Firefox or Opera everything is working correctly.
Another existing problem is that when you lose there should be a quick animation in which the snake is splitting into single fragments and going down the canvas element. Then there should be shown a text ("Koniec gry") for 2 seconds, the game should ask a player to write his name and there should be shown a highscores screen ("Wyniki"). Once again Google Chrome doesn't do anything about that and when you lose the game just freezes. There are no reports in JS Console. Here is the relevant code:

```
function gameOver() {
    stopGame();
    storage.set("activeGameData", null);
    display.gameOver(function() {
        announce("Koniec gry");
        setTimeout(function() {
            snake.game.showScreen("hiscore", board.getScore());
        }, 2500);
    });
}
```

And the `display.gameOver()`:

```
function gameOver(callback) {
    addAnimation(1000, {
        render : function(pos) {
            canvas.style.left =
                0.2 * pos * (Math.random() - 0.5) + "em";
            canvas.style.top =
                0.2 * pos * (Math.random() - 0.5) + "em";
        },
        done : function() {
            canvas.style.left = "0";
            canvas.style.top = "0";
            explode(callback);
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the `explode()` function:

```
function explode(callback) {
 // At the beginning there are many lines of some Math.random() with position,
 // velocity and rotation of every fragment of the snake which I skipped.
    addAnimation(3000, {
        before : function(pos) {
            ctx.clearRect(0,0,cols,rows);
        },
        render : function(pos, delta) {
            explodePieces(pieces, pos, delta);
        },
        done : callback
    });
}
```

And `explodePieces()`:

```
function explodePieces(pieces, pos, delta) {
    // Some calculations on every fragment's position, velocity
    // and rotation skipped.
        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(piece.pos.x, piece.pos.y);
        ctx.rotate(piece.rot * pos * Math.PI * 4);
        ctx.translate(-piece.pos.x, -piece.pos.y);
        drawObject(piece.type,
            piece.pos.x - 0.5,
            piece.pos.y - 0.5,
            1, piece.rotation
        );
        ctx.restore();
    }
}
```

The animation system is working like this: `requestAnimationFrame()` is doing the animation cycle. First argument of `addAnimation()` is the time how long should the animation last. The second is an object which may have 3 properties:

- **before**: it's preparing the canvas for every frame of animation
- **render**: it is relevant for showing every frame of animation (`pos` is the position in the animation in range 0-1)
- **done**: things which are being done after the animation is ended.

There is also a weird problem when you try to play the game on a mobile device. The game is working correctly (almost) in Safari (iOS) and Firefox Mobile (Android). I haven't checked it on any another OS. However, even in Safari and Firefox when you get switched to the highscores screen after losing, the button at the bottom ("Menu"), which is supposed to get you back into the main menu, doesn't work, although it works in desktop browsers. Here is the code which should do the thing:

```
dom.bind(backButton, "click", function(e) {
        game.showScreen("main-menu"); // The showScreen function is working for sure.
});
```

Here is the `dom.bind()`:

```
function bind(element, event, handler) {
    if (typeof element == "string") {
        element = $(element)[0];
    }
    element.addEventListener(event, handler, false)
}
```

I would appreciate any help.
Here is a github link for you to look at the code: https://github.com/lewapkon/HTML5Snake. 
The file responsible for graphics: **scripts/display.canvas.js**.
The file where the gameOver function is: **scripts/screen.game.js**.
File for highscores menu: **scripts/screen.hiscore.js**.

Comment: Please show the relevant code here. Your question shouldn't be dependent on external resources.

Comment: Pawel, I really encourage you to read the FAQ before asking a question. 

Everybody here is more than happy to help, but we're not your bug hunters.

Comment: If there's a problem when you lose the game, you can start debugging where the "gameOver" logic is

Comment: Witamy! It would help if you could try to identify the places in your code that are causing the issue and post them in your question. SO is for specific problems - though you may find some people willing to help anyway :) Powodzenia!

Comment: The large collection of ad loading scripts is causing plenty of errors in my chrome console.  You might want to start by removing those temporarily.

Comment: Unfortunately at the moment I'm using free hosting site, so I cannot do anything about the ads.
I think that you may also be thinking about these: "Ładowanie: *" and "Postęp ładowania: *". These things are just information about game files loading.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that animValue is undefined, but Firefox somehow ignores this.  It is declared in screen.settings.js, but never assigned a value.  As I have no idea what this should be defined as, please look into it and clarify your question.

Comment: animValue is a little bit badly named variable. It's just an object which holds a checkbox. The true boolean value is held in snake.settings.animations which is located in scripts/loader.js. That's why I'm binding that checkbox (animValue) to change the value of settings.animations:

    dom.bind(animValue, "click", function(e) {
   if (settings.animations == true) {
    settings.animations = false;
   } else {
    settings.animations = true;
   }
  });